# Editing crontab using a script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron, embedded-linux, auto-update

I am trying to write an embedded application upgrade script. I am running my application on Ubuntu on Beaglebone Black.

Right not, I am launching my application on power-up. To do this, I am running `launch.sh` script in crontab.

This script is as mentioned below:

```
until /root/aa_main; do
    echo "Application aa_main crashed with exit code $?. Respawning.." >&2
    echo "Crashed! $(date)" >> crashlog.txt
    sudo sync
    sudo reboot
done
```

It basically, reboots the system if my application crashes, and crontab launches the application again on reboot.

The problem is that if I want to update the application. I have to perform following steps:

1. Disable launching of the above script with `crontab -e`
2. Reboot
3. Copy and replace `aa_main`
4. Enable launching of the same script with `crontab -e`
5. Reboot

I want to automate this process. How can I do it?
Is it possible to edit crontab using a script?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't it wiser to run your script on boot using the provided init system? Is upstart the current init system for ubuntu? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto

Answer (score 4):

You can use crontab command's other options to copy the crontab to a file, modify it and install the modify version from a script:

- `crontab -l` would list the current crontab file, you can redirect this to a file of your choice and modify it
- `crontab <filename>` would install the file specified by `<filename>` as the new crontab - use this option with your  modified file and you'll get the new modified crontab